# How to make Mac OS application find private dynamic library?

Tags: macos

For Mac OS X, I've manually created an application directory `foo.app/` that contains the following files:

```
Info.plist
Contents/MacOs/foo
Frameworks/libbar.dylib
```

File `foo` is the starting executable, and was compiled from C++ using a Makefile.  File `libbar.dylib` had its id set using;

```
install_name_tool -id @rpath/libbar.dylib libbar.dylib
```

When I start the application from Finder, I get:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/libbar.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo
  Reason: image not found
```

Evidently, I need to put something in the bundle to tell the loader where to find `libbar.dylib`.  What is the best way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A very naive approach is to rename Contents/MacOs/foo to foo2 and create a new file foo in the same directory, which basically reads:

```
./foo2 —-load-lib /path/to/lib
```

But in order for that to happen the app must support this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated after JWWalker's answer enlightened me.]

The tool `install_name_tool` provides a solution: use it to add `@loader_path/../Frameworks` to the rpath for `foo`, like this:

```
$ cd foo.app/Contents/MacOS
$ install_name_tool -add_rpath @loader_path/../Frameworks foo
```

Answer (score 0):

When you link your `foo` tool, you need to tell it what the `@rpath` means.  When I look at the command line generated by my Xcode project, I see among the options fed to clang++:

```
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker "@loader_path/../Frameworks"
```

This assumes that Frameworks is a subfolder of Contents, as it normally is, not a sibling as you have indicated.

Comment: Thanks!  My goof was not testing with the current directory set to other than MacOS/.  I've updated my answer.